# Maximising sum of associated elements

Tags: graphs, arrays

I have a set of elements. Each element is connected with every other element by a path of length $l_i,_j\geq0$ (where i$\neq$j).

I have to calculate the maximum sum of path length such that I should take each vertex only once (i.e. if $l_i,_j$ is taken then I should not take $l_i,_k$).

I've thought of brute force algorithm but it would take too much time. I also thought of sorting in decreasing order of path lengths but it doesn't work in many cases.

In which direction should I think?

Comment: It seems you basically have a graph, with your set elements being vertices. When you say "connected with every other element by a path", do you mean "edge" rather than "path"? Otherwise the connections between elements (vertices) are underdetermined.

Comment: In case you do mean "edge": The NP-hard problem of determining a Hamiltonian Path is a special case of your problem (it *is* your problem, on a graph in which every edge has length 1), so your problem is NP-hard too: Don't expect a fast solution.